# How to execute multiple SQL queries in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench CE for Windows version 5.2.40.

I want to execute the following SQL queries together. However I can only execute the SQL queries by first executing the `CREATE TABLE` query, and then executing the `INSERT INTO` query and after that executing the `SELECT` query.

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    Gender VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO testTable
    VALUES
    ('Derp', 'ForeverAlone Street', 'Male'),
    ('Derpina', 'Whiterun Breezehome', 'Female')

Select * FROM testTable
```

So how do I execute the `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO` and the `SELECT` queries by one click?

Comment: Thanks Nikola K for helping me insert the inline codes. Ill make sure ill do it next time

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add a semicolon after each statement:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    Gender VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO testTable
VALUES
('Derp', 'ForeverAlone Street', 'Male'),
('Derpina', 'Whiterun Breezehome', 'Female');

SELECT * FROM testTable;
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought i would have to add GO statements. I was thinking too much. Lol.

Comment: @MohammedAjimal well its not that strange that you were thinking that cause MS-SQL uses the GO statement ;)

Comment: Adding semicolons is not enough. For example Ctrl+Enter still only executes the focused query; we also need to either click the "Execute All" icon or use Shift+Ctrl+Enter as @DotKu said in their answer.

Comment: @JoseHdez_2 Yes, that is true, but this wasn't a problem for the OP at the moment he asked the question, I believe.

Comment: Salute to awesomeness @bfavaretto

Answer (score 56):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run everything with semicolon end.

For Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: If you came here from googling "mysql workbench only running first query" then this is your answer.

Comment: I was going mad why MySQL workbench is not executing all the queries. Turns out it is not a feature to run all queries by default. You need to use the command mentioned above or click the bolt icon in top navbar in MySQL workbench